# Method of moments when the first moment is $0$

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions, parameter-estimation

I have a quick question regarding the method of moments estimator.

Generally, when you have $k$ parameters you want to estimate, it suffices to find $k$ equations using $k$ moments.

If you are estimating one parameter, and you find that the first moment is equal to $0$, what do you do? Do you find the second moment and use that as the estimate?

Thanks!

Comment: In the case $k = 1$ and you have a single parameter $\theta$, if the mean is given by $f(\theta)$ and your first moment is zero then this is just the same as solving $f(\theta) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, you should take second moment to construct estimator. Say, in the case of uniform distribution on $[-\theta,\theta]$ MOM for $\theta$ cannot be constructed from the first moment.